# extracting multiple data from table row in BS4

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

in the code below I am trying to extract IP addresses and ports of http://free-proxy-list.net  from the table using `BeautifulSoup`.

But every time I get the whole row which is useless because I can't separate IP addresses from their ports.

How can I get IP and port separated?

Here is my code:

```
        def get_proxy(self):
            response = requests.get(self.url)
            soup = bs(response.content,'html.parser')
            data_list = [tr for tr in soup.select('tr') if tr.td]

            for i in data_list:
                print(i.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I had to add the isnumeric() condition to make sure that the code doesn't include the data from another table which is present on the same website.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from collections import defaultdict

def get_proxy(URL):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(response.content,'html.parser')
    mapping = defaultdict()
    for tr in soup.select('tr'):
        if len(list(tr)) == 8:
            ip_val = str(list(tr)[0].text)
            port_val = str(list(tr)[1].text)
            if port_val.isnumeric():
                mapping[ip_val] = port_val


    for items in mapping.keys():
        print("IP:",items)
        print("PORT:",mapping[items])

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    url = "http://free-proxy-list.net"
    get_proxy(url)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code,
instead of -

`i.text` you could use `i.getText(' ,')` (or with another separator of your choice other than ,). 
That will give you comma separated IP and Ports.

Moreover for convenience you could load the proxy list into a dataframe as well.

Make the following changes/additions to your code -

```
soup = bs(response.content,'html.parser')

data_list = [tr for tr in soup.select('tr') if tr.td]


data_list2 = [tr.getText(' ,') for tr in soup.select('tr') if tr.td]

#for i in data_list:
      #print(i.text)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_list2,columns=['proxy_list'])

df_proxyList= df['proxy_list'].str.split(',', expand=True)[0:300]
```

**df_proxyList** would look like (with few garbage columns) -

[image]